# $g(x) = 5(x+3)^2-2$ determine the interval(s) on which the function is increasing and decreasing

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm working through a textbook exercise and am asked to find the intervals in which $g(x) = 5(x+3)^2-2$ is increasing and decreasing.

The solution provided is decreasing on $(-\infty, -3)$ and then increasing on $(-3, \infty)$.

I cannot see how to arrive at this conclusion. These are exercises at the end of a chapter on the transformation of functions though the author may be including bits from previous chapters, however I searched through recent chapters and there was only a section on determining where a function is increasing or decreasing based on a graph, so visually.

In this case does the question expect me to derive the solution based on formula? Is that possible? Or am I perhaps expected to draw a graph for some arbitrary values and then try to determine the increasing and decreasing points?

Comment: Did you mean $5(x\color{red}-3)^2-2,$ or did you mean $(-\infty,\color{red}-3)$ and $(\color{red}-3,\infty)$?

Comment: Hi thanks for pointing that out, I have updated my question to match the textbook now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $-2$ at the end is just translating the function down, it will not change if it is increasing or decreasing. Than you have a parabola, so you need to look at the vertex, which is at $-3$, since you have $(x-(-3))^2$. This is similar to $x^2$, just translated horizontally from $0$ to $-3$. You know that the parabola has values of $+\infty$ at $x=\pm\infty$, so it's decreasing from $-\infty$ to the vertex at $-3$, and increasing afterwards.

P.S. see @JWTanner 's comment

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $$g'(x)=10(x+3)$$ so you have to solve $$g'(x)\geq 0$$ and $$g'(x)<0$$So compute $$g(x_2)-g(x_1)$$ with h $$x_1<x_2$$

Comment: the question tag was *pre*calculus

Answer (score 1):

If you know (or *see*) that translations do not modify monotonicity, you could start from the function
$$
Y=5X^2
$$
and put $X=x-3$ and $Y=y+2$. A translation in the $y$ variable does not alter monotonicity inteervals. A translation in the $x$ variable just translates accordingly the monotonicity intervals. Since $Y=5X^2$ is decreasin on $(-\infty,0)$ and increasing on $(0,+\infty)$, then $y=5(x-3)^2-2$ is decreasing on ... and increasing on ...